# mysql how to specify condition on an aggregated column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with order id, product id and the quantity of each product of that order (like in the table below). And I have to select the order_id and it's total quantity where the quantity is more than 5.

```
+----------+------------+----------+
| order_id | product_id | quantity |
+----------+------------+----------+
|        1 |          1 |        6 |
|        1 |          2 |        1 |
|        2 |          3 |        3 |
|        2 |          2 |        2 |
|        3 |          1 |        3 |
|        3 |          3 |        5 |
+----------+------------+----------+
```

What I've tried is

```sql
SELECT order_id, SUM(quantity) AS qty
FROM order_product
WHERE qty > 5 /* <-- Cannot use qty here */
GROUP BY order_id;

ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'qty' in 'where clause'
```

AFAIK the where clause executed before summing the quantity columns so I cannot use qty there but is there any way to run the condition after the aggregation or is there any other way to solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To filter after aggregation, you can use a `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT order_id,
       sum(quantity) AS qty
       FROM order_product
       GROUP BY order_id
       HAVING sum(quantity) > 5;
```

Comment: ... also the output alias instead of the expression can be used: `HAVING qty > 5`. (may be useful for OP)

Comment: How can this completely basic question not be a duplicate. And how did this end up being a HNQ?

Comment: @Barmar - I find it easier/faster to answer a question than to look for a dup _and_ study the potential dup to see if it really matches.  (I find a lot of "closed as dup" questions there were not a good match.)  Otherwise, I agree; it must be a dup.